# Error trying to connect Celery through SQS using STS

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs, kombu

I'm trying to use Celery with SQS as broker. In order to use the SQS from my container I need to assume a role and for that I'm using STS. My code looks like this:

```py
role_info = {
    'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/my-role-execution',
    'RoleSessionName': 'roleExecution'
}
sts_client = boto3.client('sts', region_name='eu-central-1')
credentials = sts_client.assume_role(**role_info)

aws_access_key_id = credentials["Credentials"]['AccessKeyId']
aws_secret_access_key = credentials["Credentials"]['SecretAccessKey']
aws_session_token = credentials["Credentials"]["SessionToken"]

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = aws_access_key_id
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = aws_secret_access_key
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = 'eu-central-1'
os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = aws_session_token

broker = "sqs://"
backend = 'redis://redis-service:6379/0'

celery = Celery('tasks', broker=broker, backend=backend)

celery.conf["task_default_queue"] = 'my-queue'
celery.conf["broker_transport_options"] = {
    'region': 'eu-central-1',
    'predefined_queues': {
       'my-queue': {
            'url': 'https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/my-queue'
        }
    }
}
```

In the same file I have the following task:

```py
@celery.task(name='my-queue.my_task')
def my_task(content) -> int:
    print("hello")
    return 0
```

When I execute the following code I get an error:

```py
[2020-09-24 10:38:03,602: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ClientError('An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListQueues operation: Access to the resource https://eu-central-1.queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 921, in create_channel
    return self._avail_channels.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 208, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/connection.py", line 23, in start
    c.connection = c.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 405, in connect
    conn = self.connection_for_read(heartbeat=self.amqheartbeat)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 412, in connection_for_read
    self.app.connection_for_read(heartbeat=heartbeat))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 439, in ensure_connected
    callback=maybe_shutdown,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 422, in ensure_connection
    callback, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 341, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 275, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 823, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 778, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 941, in establish_connection
    self._avail_channels.append(self.create_channel(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 923, in create_channel
    channel = self.Channel(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 100, in __init__
    self._update_queue_cache(self.queue_name_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 105, in _update_queue_cache
    resp = self.sqs.list_queues(QueueNamePrefix=queue_name_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 337, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 656, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListQueues operation: Access to the resource https://eu-central-1.queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.
```

If I use `boto3` **directly** without Celery, I'm able to connect to the queue and retrieve data without this error. I don't know why Celery/Kombu try to list queues when I specify the `predefined_queues` configuration, tha is used to avoid these behavior (from docs):

> If you want Celery to use a set of predefined queues in AWS, and to never attempt to list SQS queues, nor attempt to create or delete them, pass a map of queue names to URLs using the predefined_queue_urls setting

[Source here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html#predefined-queues)

Anyone know what happens? How I should modify my code in order to make it work?. Seems that Celery is not using the credentials at all.

The versions I'm using:

```py
celery==4.4.7
boto3==1.14.54
kombu==4.5.0
```

Thanks!

PS: I created and [issue](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1255) in Github to track if this can be a library error or not...

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?
I 'm still struggling with this exact same error even after using the latest dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem updating dependencies to the latest versions:

```
celery==5.0.0
boto3==1.14.54
kombu==5.0.2
pycurl==7.43.0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get `celery==4.4.7` and `kombu==4.6.11` working by setting the following configuration option:

```py
celery.conf["task_create_missing_queues"] = False
```